# The summer equivalent of "winterize"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I *winterize* my car in preparation for the harsh winter.
I want to say I *summerize* my snow blower for summer storage.
But "summerize" seems not to be an English word, and in any case, it is
homophonous with *summarize*.

Comment: Go ahead and use it, in context no one will notice.

Comment: You can certainly [***overwinter***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22overwinter+the%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) something transitively (things that need to be stored in some special way during the winter months, for example). But intransitive use *(Some wealthy pensioners like to overwinter in the Bahamas)* is far more common. The same intransitive use does occurs (though far less often) with ***oversummer***.

Comment: But never say never - [here's one written instance](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22oversummer+the+virus%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) containing transitive ***overwinter*** and ***oversummer***, both in the same sentence.

Comment: The following source cites the  term as a U.S. colloquialism: https://books.google.it/books?id=p0h5AAAAIAAJ&q=%22summerize%22&dq=%22summerize%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=VBxjVbS3BYbSyAP8iYGwDg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBA

Comment: You _winterize_ your car with the intent of using it during winter, but you seem to want to _summerize_ your snow blower with the intent of _not_ using it during summer. These seem to me to be two somewhat different concepts.

Comment: I regularly winterize my bicycles for use in the winter.  When summer rolls around, I usually summerize then as well.  That's also the terminology I have regularly used to describe it.

Comment: @anemone: Point taken. But I also winterize my lawn mower.

Comment: Another option is ***summerify***.

Comment: The opposite of *hibernate* is *estivate*. It is seldom transitive.

Answer (score 4):

My google dictionary led [here](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=summerize):

> S: (v) summerize, summerise (prepare for summer) "summerize your car"; "summerize a house"

So I wouldn't throw summerize out the window yet.

Comment: I'd find it hard to recommend its usage, though. Can you cite a dictionary for it?